# Python & OpenCV - VideoCapture.read() always returns false

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, python-3.5

I need to extract frames from a video at a given time, and I'm using OpenCV for it. I'm using Linux Mint 18.1, but it must also run on Ubuntu.

This code example is not working for me:

```
import cv2

print('making screenshot from {0}'.format('/tmp/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4'))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,1000)
ret,frame = cap.read()
print(ret)                      # This is false
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame) # Creates an empty file
```

(I've checked that the path of the video is correct and that the file is not corrupted).

I have installed the Python OpenCV 3.3.0 version:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'
```

I've compiled and installed the source for OpenCV (with the `WITH_FFMPEG=ON` option):

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git /tmp/opencv-3                                                                                                                                                                                
/tmp/opencv-3                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
mkdir -p release                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
cd release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
cmake -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..                                                                                                                                                   
make                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
sudo make install
```

The output of `ffmpeg -version` is the following:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Its probably an issue with the mp4 format of your file. Convert it to .avi and try if that's alright. You can use vlc media player to convert if you have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I.Newton. Unfortunately keeps returning "False" after converting the file to .avi.

Comment: ok, now that shouldn't have happened. once try bringing the video to the working directory instead of giving the path

Comment: Still doesn't work having the video in the working directory and with the relative path. I've also set 777 permissions to the video, for if was a permission problem, but didn't work neither.

Is there a way for debugging it? Getting just a "False" is not very helpful...

Comment: Did you get an answer for this

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture(video_path) also returns False ?